# Turret aiming code

Tags: vector, linear-algebra

I'm currently working on turret aiming code. If I can't hit the center of the object (due to an obstacle), I want to see if I can hit any of the object. To do this i'll get it's bounds, and check in between that range instead of doing a full 360 sweep. I can calculate 1 and 2 (sort points by angle to turret/blue dot), but how do I ensure I get sweep A and not B?

[image]

Comment: I guess you could transform the points to local space and calculate the position and angle from there.

Comment: Yes but how do I ensure 1 is the start and 2 is the end and not vice versa?

Comment: Rethinking it you don't have to calculate it to local space as long the points are calculated in the same space as the turret is orientated in. Let's assume in your picture the default orientation is to the right, making point 1s bearing at 270 degrees. and point 2s bearing about 178 degrees. Then simply sweep from 178 to 270. This is assuming right is 0 and left is 180. So simply reverse the sweep from 270 to 178 or simply reverse the everything where left is 0 and right is 180. But I don't think any system does that.

Comment: this might also help : http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/53551/324957.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I was origionally going to post Brams answer, however I forgot that you are already pointing at the center, and we can use the knowledge of point 1 and point 2 to our benefit.

If your turret is already aiming at the center of the object, no complicated angle math is necessary at all.

You know point 2 is to the right (with respect to your turret) and point 1 is to the left.  You simply will scan from the left angle, clock wise, to the right angle via subtracting some constant angle value to sweep, no need for any complicated logic, and no chance to accidentally go the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

You always sweep over the smallest delta-angle.

There is always one delta which is smaller than 180° and one that is bigger than 180°.

In your example, one range is appr 90° and the other 270°.

That said, your original problem of hitting partly obscured objects can also be handled in a simpler and more elegant way:

Every frame, pick a random point on the target, and check for visibility. If it is visible, you can aim for it and shoot. If it is not visible, then next frame you may be more lucky in the choice of random spot on target.

This method is easier to implement, and will also generalize to 3D much better.